# Same key value pair in json2xls misses value in csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, json2xls

i'm trying to convert json data to xls using json2xls. everything wokrss fine but when my key has similar value it shows blank in sheet
eg:
{name:"blake",
email:"abc@gmail",
service123:"123"}
it has a column named service123 but it's value gets missing in cell and if i change it to service it displays the value. any resolve for this

any solutions or guidelines will be helpfull

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.